# Simple console app in C# .NET CORE 3.1 to test a local DynamoDB table running in Docker

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-dynamodb

Folks,

I have created a very simple console application in C# .NET 3.1 based on the following example:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/access-amazon-dynamodb-locally-in-net-core-console-application/

There is nothing proprietary about this example. It's super simple. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Dynamodb
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var clientConfig = new AmazonDynamoDBConfig();
            clientConfig.ServiceURL = "http://localhost:8000";

            AmazonDynamoDBClient client = null;
            try
            {
                client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(clientConfig);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            var tableName = "Token";            
            var hash = "{\"tenant_id\":\"c86f34aa-85c1-42ae-af67-9b0428231033\"}";
            var range = "{}";
            var table = Table.LoadTable(client, tableName);
            var filter = new QueryFilter("range", QueryOperator.Equal, range);
            var search = table.Query(hash, filter);
            var set = await search.GetNextSetAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that it breaks when I new up the client. The error I get is:
"Invalid region endpoint provided."

I have tried setting the Region, configuring from the appsettings.json, injecting environment variables, etc. None of that worked. I tried .NET CORE 5.0. Nope.

To cut to the chase. The AWS NUGET packages are the latest available. I am running DynamoDB from Docker using the latest WSL 2 on a windows 10. The docker command line looks like this:

```
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local   -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb
```

I can access my table using AWS CLI from within BASH and from a simple windows DOS prompt on port 8000. I can connect to localhost:8000 inside of NoSQL Workbench and see my table and its data.

I have also tried using the DynamoDB service from the latest LOCALSTACK docker image. I could not figure out how to easily override it to enable SharedDb. I am not convinced that it matters. However, I had to use SharedDb to see my DynamoDB table in the NoSQL Workbench tool. So, I focused on the AWS Docker image for DynamoDB.

Anyway, I have exhausted my investigation into this after two days of searching for answers. I had the same experience on yet another machine just to double check. I am convinced this is not a fluke.

I am only interested in answers if you have encountered this problem and know how to overcome it. I find it inconceivable that having reproduced the problem on two different machines that this is a unique problem. In the meantime I will use POSTGRES SQL. It's not my preference, but I have commitments to deliver.

Comment: Have you tried to set the region manually? Possibly on the clientconfig object?

Comment: Why are you trying to wrap a DynamoDB table in a container environment as opposed to using the cloud based version which is very easy to connect to using AWS SDK for .NET. Just wondering.

Comment: as for trying things.... I have tried setting the region manually, through configuration and via environment variables. I thought I mentioned that. As for why, well, because it's a requirement that we localize certain resources to expedite full stack feature driven development. It's not a preference or an opinion. It's supposed to work. It's my experience that it does not for 3.1 CORE or 5.0 CORE.

Comment: anyway, it works, or it does not. Let's get to the truth.

Comment: Over 30 views and no answers. Shocking. Honestly, I am not surprised. Could it be that it just doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I addressed the issue by setting the RegionEndpoint and Profile to use (probably not necessary if you have your default region set in your default credentials; but I use lots of different profiles and regions).

```
var clientConfig = new AmazonDynamoDBConfig();
clientConfig.RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1;
clientConfig.Profile = new Profile("myProfile");

DynamoDBContext context = new DynamoDBContext(client);
await context.SaveAsync(...)/QueryAsync(...), whatever;
```